# Jquery datepicker not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was trying to load jQuery datepicker on dynamic content. It works on static content. But couldn't load the datepicker when i add the dynamic content. what could be possible error?
Html Part:

```
<div class="col-md-10 dynamic-field mb-3" id="dynamic-field-1" >
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="field" class="hidden-md">Select Item</label>
                <!-- <input type="text" id="field" required class="form-control" name="type_of_cultivation[]" /> -->
                <select class="form-control" id="field" required name="type_of_cultivation[]">
                  <option value="">Choose  item</option> 
                    @foreach($items as $row)
                      <option value="{{$row->id}}">{{$row->item_name}} - {{$row->item_unit}}</option>
                    @endforeach 
                 </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="field" class="hidden-md">Cultivation Date</label>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control datepicker" required placeholder="2023-02-28" name="cultivation_date[]" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Harvest Date</label>
                <input type="text"  class="form-control datepicker" required placeholder="2023-03-28" name="harvest_date[]">
            </div>
        </div>
       
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Part:

```
  var datePickerOptions = {
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    firstDay: 1,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
}
   
  $('body').on('focus',".datepicker", function(){
   $(this).datepicker(datePickerOptions);
});
 

$(document).ready(function() {
 var buttonAdd = $("#add-button");
  var buttonRemove = $("#remove-button");
  var className = ".dynamic-field";
  var count = 0;
  var field = "";
  var maxFields =50;

  function totalFields() {
    return $(className).length;
  }

  function addNewField() 
  {
    count = totalFields() + 1;
    field = $("#dynamic-field-1").clone();
    field.attr("id", "dynamic-field-" + count);
    field.children("label").text("Field " + count);
    field.find("input").val("");
    $(className + ":last").after($(field));

  }

  function removeLastField() {
    if (totalFields() > 1) {
      $(className + ":last").remove();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to remove `datepicker` data and `hasDatepicker` class from cloned element as datepicker attaches id to the element, so do the following:

```
....
function addNewField() {
  count = totalFields() + 1;
  field = $("#dynamic-field-1").clone();
  field.attr("id", "dynamic-field-" + count);
  field.children("label").text("Field " + count);
  field.find("input").val("");
  
  // remove hasDatepicker class and remove datepicker data
  // so that new instance is attached to this field
  // edited
  field.find("input.datepicker")
    .removeAttr("id")
    .removeClass('hasDatepicker')
    .removeData('datepicker')
    .unbind()
    .datepicker(datePickerOptions);
  
  $(className + ":last").after($(field));

}
.....
```

Comment: it replaced the previous datepicker date.  If i want to store data on dynamic content. It replaced the previous date and not set on initialized on.

Comment: @Hola check the edit, and this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n18as2y7/

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti you can post snippets here instead of on external sites. Just click the `[<>]` snippet editor button